# $\lambda$-definability and structure preserved by homomorphisms

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

I imagine there are some standard results that bear on this, but I'm having trouble finding a proof or refutation of it.

Some prelimary definitions.

A Henkin structure $A = (A^\cdot, ⟦\cdot⟧_A)$ for the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus with a single base type $o$ consists of a set $A^\sigma$ for each type $\sigma$ such that $A^{\sigma\to\tau}\subseteq (A^\tau)^{A^\sigma}$, $⟦\cdot⟧$ is a function mapping assignments and simply typed $\lambda$-term to elements of the appropriate domains satisfying the usual clauses: $⟦x⟧^g=g(x)$, $⟦\lambda x.M⟧^g = a \mapsto ⟦M⟧^{g[a/x]}$, $⟦MN⟧=⟦M⟧⟦N⟧)$.

A homomorphism between structures $A$ and $B$ is a type-indexed family  of functions $h^\sigma:A^\sigma \to B^\sigma$, such that $h^\sigma(⟦ M⟧_A^g)=⟦ M⟧_B^{h\circ g}$ for every term $M$ of type $\sigma$.

An element $d\in A^\sigma$ is $\lambda$-definable iff $d = ⟦M⟧_A$ for some closed term $M$, and is $\lambda$-definable from elements $a_1...a_n$ of the structure if $d = ⟦M⟧(a_1)...(a_n)$ for some closed term $M$.

QUESTION: is it true that if $A$ is a Henkin model with $A^o$ infinite, and $d\in A^\sigma$ is an element of that is preserved by homomorphisms, in the sense that for every $h,h':A\to B$, $h^\sigma(d)=h'^\sigma(d)$, then $d$ is $\lambda$-definable?

(There are analogous questions for more general classes of models of the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus, that I would also be interested to know about if the answer depends on the type of model.)

Comment: Are there any base types? What is known about them?

Comment: Oops, I meant to specify that the base types were infinite. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, you're more or less (because there are no products) describing a sub-ccc of $\mathsf{Set}$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to define "sub-CCC", but if you add products and treat the domains $A^\sigma$ as objects with $Hom(A^\sigma,A^\tau)=A^{\sigma\to\tau}$, a Henkin model is a CCC that is also a subcategory of set (but, potentially, with different exponential objects).

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the exponential objects are different. Thanks.

Comment: If you take the elements that are preseved by all homomorphisms (they need a name), do they also form a Henkin structure? And if so, what if you then repeat the process, does it stop?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. If your new (shrunk) domain $B^\sigma$ is a proper subset of  $A^\sigma$, and $B^{\sigma\to\tau}$ is a subset of $A^{\sigma\to\tau}$ the new structure is not Henkin, since $B^{\sigma\to\tau}$ is not a set of functions with domain $B^\sigma$.

Comment: But it also seems unlikely to me that the applicative structure consisting of "invariant" elements will even be isomorphic to a Henkin structure. For instance, the substructure of $A$ consisting of $\lambda$-definable elements is not extensional since the Church numerals of type $(o\to o)\to o\to o$ are distinct (since the base types are infinite), but there is only one element in the domain $o\to o$, identity.

That said, there is a variant of my question for the wider class of (possibly non-functional) applicative structures that are models of the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus.